# Skip BOM using BOMInputStream and retrieve byte[] without BOM

Tags: java, spring, byte-order-mark

I have an xml file with BOM(UTF-8 encoding). The file comes as a `byte[]`. I need to skip the BOM and later convert these bytes into a String.

This is how my code looks like now:

```
BOMInputStream bomInputStream = new BOMInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestDTO.getFile())); // getFile() returns byte[]

bomInputStream.skip(bomInputStream.hasBOM() ? bomInputStream.getBOM().length() : 0);

validationService.validate(new String(/*BYTE[] WITHOUT BOM*/)); // throws NullPointerException
```

I'm using BOMInputStream. I have couple of issues. The first one is that the `bomInputStream.hasBOM()` returns `false`. The second one, I'm not sure how to retrive the `byte[]` from `bomInputStream` later on, because `bomInputStream.getBOM().getBytes()` throws NullPointerException. Thanks for any help!

BOMInputStream documentation link:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor without boolean include parameter excludes the BOM, hence `hasBOM()` returns false, and no BOM will be included. And the String will not contain a BOM.
Then `getBOM()` returns null!

```
byte[] xml = requestDTO.getFile();
int bomLength = 0;
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
try (BOMInputStream bommedInputStream = new BOMInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml),
            true)) {
    if (bommedInputStream.hasBOM()) {
        bomLength = bommedInputStream.getBOM().length();
        charset = Charset.forName(bommedInputStream.getBOMCharsetName());
    } else {
        // Handle <?xml ... encoding="..." ... ?>.
        String t = new String(xml, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
        String enc = t.replace("(?sm).*<\\?xml.*\\bencoding=\"([^\"]+)\".*\\?>.*$", "$1");
        ... or such to fill charset ...
    }
}
String s = new String(xml, charset).replaceFirst("^\uFEFF", ""); // Remove BOM.
validationService.validate(s);
```

Removing the BOM could be done using the bomLength. BOMInputStream can give us the charset for the many UTF variants.

The String constructor without encoding/charset (as you used) will use the default platform encoding. As the BOM is Unicode code pointer U+FEFF, you can simply pass `"\uFEFF"`.

Comment: ok, got it, and how to retrieve the string/bytes from bomInputStream after skipping the bom(if it was found).

Comment: A second BOMInputStream, as you wrote, or simply using the BOM length to skip those bytes before passing on an ByteArrayInputStream.

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite understand. I meant how do I retrieve my xml bytes without BOM from bomInputStream. As I understand the `bomInputStream.getBOM().getBytes()` wouldn't return me the original xml without BOM

Comment: Will add it to the answer.

Comment: No, you see, I need to send a string without BOM to `validationService`. So sending a string to `validationService` would be the last step.

Comment: Okay understood now

Comment: Sorry if I'm not making it clear enought. The `validationService` is an external method not connected with BOM, it validates the xml content, like id, name etc. Let me explain it one more time. 1) I receive byte[] with BOM 2) I remove BOM from byte[] 3) I send byte[] without BOM to another services

Comment: In your example you're getting the `bomLength` but not using it later on. So then why not just use the last two lines then? Wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222706/discussion-between-developer1-and-joop-eggen).